# SPNEGO Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, http-status-code-401, spnego

Trying to write a selenium test case in python for software built by IBM. Getting the following error.

(Tried installing `requests-gssapi` of Python but did not work.)

> An error occurred while communicating with the server.
>   HTTP 401: SPNEGO authentication is not supported on this client.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Did you google the error? First result on google was an IBM site.

Comment: [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21394592) ,solution is not clear

Comment: Figure it out man, You are a software developer. I don't even know selenium. I'm not here to give you a solution. SO is there to help you in the right direction, but you didn't provide anything on what you have done, your code or anything? We are not here to solve your problems, but to help you look in the right place for a solution.